# Can't create sprite inside my own function

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Trying to spawn target periodically using .time.addEvent. But the callback function won't spawn the sprite. Console spits out TypeError: this.add is undefined (the one inside the spawnTarget function that I created). I've placed the sprite outside of the spawnTarget function and it works fine!.

```
export class StandarModeScene extends Phaser.Scene {

constructor() {
    super('standarMode_scene');
}

preload() {
    this.load.image('target', '../assets/target1.png');
}

create() {
    this.cameras.main.setBackgroundColor('#302e2d'); //setting the background to grey
    let target = this.add.sprite(Phaser.Math.Between(0, 600), Phaser.Math.Between(0, 800), 'target'); //add sprite

    let targetSpawnInterval = 350;

    function spawnTarget() {
       this.add.sprite(Phaser.Math.Between(0, 600), Phaser.Math.Between(0, 800), 'target');
    }

    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: targetSpawnInterval,
        callback: spawnTarget,
        loop: true
    });

}
```

I've also tried

```
function spawnTarget() {
    target.add.sprite(Phaser.Math.Between(0, 600), Phaser.Math.Between(0, 800), 'target');
}
```

But the TypeError says target.add is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not preserved inside the spawnTarget function.
Try to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function:

```
this.time.addEvent({
    delay: targetSpawnInterval,
    callback: spawnTarget.bind(this),
    loop: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're running into a 'this' scope problem. Checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this for more info.

As a solution, I'd think moving your 'spawnTarget' function declaration outside of your 'create' function would be the easiest. Or you can look at passing a this context to your function with call/apply.